# ¿Como poner color de fondo a texto y no a toda la caja o línea?

Tags: html, css

Deseo poner color de fondo mediante `CSS` a un texto, pero únicamente al texto y no a la línea entera del texto.

El color de fondo del texto sería negro, por ejemplo.

**Código:**

```css
#visor_imagenes {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h2 id='visor_imagenes'>VISOR DE IMAGENES</h2>
```

Comment: Y que error te sale? lo veo bien, no se que necesitas.

Answer (score 6):

Una opción sería diferenciar los elementos.

- Poner un `<span>` para el texto con una clase donde apliques el estilo de color de texto y de fondo requerido sólo para el texto. Dado que el `span` es un contenedor en línea (`inline`), te permitirá aplicar el color y el fondo específicamente al texto dentro de él y no a todo el bloque, como ocurre con el `h2`, que es un elemento en bloque (`block`).
- Dejar el id `visor_imagenes` sólo para el encabezado y para centrar el texto que habrá en él.

Ejemplo:

```css
#visor_imagenes {
  text-align: center;
}

.blanco-rojo {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2 id='visor_imagenes'><span class="blanco-rojo">VISOR DE IMAGENES</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 5):

En una mezcla de ambas respuestas te sugiero lo siguiente, si lo que quieres es que el **título h1** se coloque solo en negro de fondo, pero que cubra solo el texto y no el bloque entero, sería algo así:

```css
body{ text-align: center }

.titulo{
 background: black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: arial;
}

.dos{ display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<h1 class="titulo uno">
Esto es solo un ejemplo sin el inline-block
</h1>

<h1 class="titulo dos">
Esto es solo un ejemplo con el inline-block
</h1>
```

Si quieres que solo dentro del título, solo un texto se subraye de color negro, entonces deberás encerrar esa palabra en una etiqueta inline, por ejemplo: **span**.

```css
body{ text-align: center }

.titulo{
 background: black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: arial;
}

.dos{ display: inline-block; }

.titulo span{ background: red; color: white;}

.tres { background: initial; color: initial;}

.tres span{ background: black; }
```

```html
<h1 class="titulo uno">
Ejemplo sin el inline-block, <span>con texto resaltado</span>
</h1>

<h1 class="titulo dos">
Ejemplo con el inline-block, con <span>texto resaltado</span>
</h1>

<h1 class="titulo tres">
Ejemplo con solo <span>texto resaltado</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

No se si entiendo tu pregunta, entiendo que lo que quieres es que digamos este simplemente subrayada la frase de tu `h2` ¿no?

De ser así se me ocurre esto

```
#visor_imagenes{
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
}

echo "<h2 id='visor_imagenes'>VISOR DE IMAGENES</h2>";
```

Convirte el h2 a elemento en línea y ya funciona.